# Why does the LM2596 have 1.23V reference voltage instead of 1.235V?

Tags: switching-regulator

According to the functional block diagram below.

[image]

I know it is not much difference, just 0.005V but if it was 1.235V it should say it.

Maybe I'm understanding something fully.

Comment: Looks like a typo. Follow the listed range in the datasheet and contact TI to correct it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual number will be specified by the specifications in the datasheet. The TI part, [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf) datasheet, specifies that it will be between 1.193V and 1.267V at 25°C Tj, and between 1.18V and 1.28V over the full temperature range.

The average of the two in both cases is 1.230V.

Early datasheets (Natsemi) have 1.23V in the diagram, however Onsemi and later datasheets have 1.235.

You can either consider it a typo or consider that the amplifier has a bit of offset  built-in, either way ignore that number and use the specification range for the purposes of calculating the feedback network.